# Interpretation in Fourier-Laplace domain

Tags: fourier-transform, greens-functions

The Green's function describing the distribution of particles sent from $\def\v#1{\boldsymbol{#1}}\def\u#1{\hat{\v#1}}\v r=0$ at $t=0$ uniformly in every directions is, in two dimensions
$$ G(r,t)=\frac{\delta(r-ct)}{2\pi r}.$$
Taking the Hankel transform, the equivalent of Fourier transform for function depending only on $r$ in two dimensions, and the Laplace transform for time, we find 
$$\widehat{\widetilde G}(k,s)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{s^2+c^2k^2}}.$$

Consider now a function $f$ that has a Laplace transform $\widehat f$. Then the function
$$ \frac{f\left(\sqrt{t^2-r^2/c^2}\right)}{2\pi c\sqrt{t^2-r^2/c^2}}$$
has for Hankel-Laplace transform the function
$$ c\frac{\widehat f\left(\sqrt{s^2+c^2k^2}\right)}{\sqrt{s^2+c^2k^2}}
=\widehat{\widetilde G}(k,s)c\widehat f\left(\frac1{\widehat{\widetilde  G}(k,s)}\right).$$

In other words, in a two dimensional space, any function of $\sqrt{t^2-r^2/c^2}$ (which looks like a relativistic proper time) in the space-time domain is a function of the isotropic propagator in the conjugated space. Can someone see a physical interpretation for this ?